# JS (LOOPS): Finding the perfect filtering loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

Today, I started a ridiculously simple task that grew as a problem the more I worked on it. You see, I am trying to make a JS functional sidebar that will filter elements in a container according to the filtering property in each element. If it is a part of the (Filtering rule) the element should display. Else, It should display none

```html
<ul id="filteringSidebar">


  <li>Color Is Green</li>
  <li>Color Is Yellow</li>
  <li>Color Is Blue</li>
  <li>Color Is Violet</li>
  <li>Color Is Magenta</li>
  <li>Color Is Orange</li>
  <li>Color Is Indigo</li>
  <li>Color Is Gray</li>
  <li>Color Is Black</li>

</ul>



<div id="elementsContainer">

  <div> Blue </div>
  <div> Magenta </div>
  <div> Magenta </div>
  <div> Yellow </div>
  <div> Blue </div>
  <div> Orange </div>
  <div> Orange </div>
  <div> Indigo </div>
  <div> Blue </div>
  <div> Gray </div>
  <div> Blue </div>
  <div> Black </div>
  <div> Orange </div>

</div>
```

This is a very raw explaination of what i'm aiming to achieve, but the whole idea is for one to be able to click one or more of the list items in the UL with ID of `filteringSidebar` and expect the results according to user input. (IF YELLOW AND ORANGE IS PRESSED, THERE SHOULD ONLY BE YELLOW AND ORANGE ELEMENTS DISPLAYING IN THE DIV WITH ID OF `elementsContainer`)

Comment: Can you share your filtering code with us and describe the specific issue you're having in getting it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here I have give a different id for each `<li>` item and then used bootstrap for styling. Then each `<div>` hide via using bootstrap `d-none`. Using Query each button was assigned to a different function and these functions will toggle the `d-none`. This is just a basic and there may be more easy way to do this.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <script>
    function showDivGreen() {

      $("#green").each(function() {
        $('#green').toggleClass('d-none');
      })
    }

    function showDivYellow() {
      $('#yellow').toggleClass('d-none');
    }

    function showDivBlue() {
      $('#blue').toggleClass('d-none');
    }
  </script>
  <ul id="filteringSidebar">


    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnGreen" onclick="showDivGreen();" value="green"><li>Color Is Green</li> </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnYellow" onclick="showDivYellow();" value="yellow"><li>Color Is Yellow</li>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnBlue" onclick="showDivBlue();" value="blue"><li>Color Is Blue</li>


</ul>

<div class="row">

<div id="blue" class="bg bg-primary col-md-4 hidden d-none " > Blue </div>
<div id="yellow"   class="bg bg-warning  col-md-4 d-none" > Yellow </div>
<div  id="green"   class="bg bg-success col-md-4 d-none" > Green </div>


</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```